# What to do when your boss overrides your decision?

Tags: management, hiring

I have been interviewing people for retail operation manager. The hard requirement is experience in retail, fashion, and training.

My boss referred a friend of his to me. His friend comes from the food and beverage industry. Let's call him Tom.

Tom failed the interview with my coworker. My boss later asked me to interviewed Tom, which I did. I don't think Tom has what it takes and I gave him a No. I talked to my boss about the results and he is upset about it.

Last week, he asked me to proceed Tom to the next step. I don't think it's the right thing to do because his friend doesn't add value to the team. At the same time, I don't want to burn the bridge with my boss.

What should I do in this situation?

**Update**
I sent an email detailing my feedback and recommendation to my boss and HR. I stated in the email that I did my part by providing feedback. My boss will make the hiring decision on this case

Comment: We can't tell you what you "should" do. You need to work out whether it's more important to you personally to put your foot down over this (up to quitting if you really think it's that important) or take the easy path with your boss.

Comment: Is the boss also the owner of the company?

Comment: Does your company have an ethics or compliance officer? If so, have you considered contacting them? Most companies frown on nepotism like this.

Comment: Is there any way this hiring decision (even though you didn't make it) could reflect negatively on you? I'd start covering your tracks and clearly record that this hiring is not your decision, but rather your bosses.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel we don't have compliance office. The closest one we got is HR

Comment: @TheEvilMetal His friend will work in our department. It will drain my (and our team) time and energy

Comment: @CodeProject Could you please clarify "to the next step" - is it just another round of interviews (your boss may be just acting nice) or is it final job offer/start working stage (as all current answers imply) ?

Comment: I read you "**Update**" note. You are so courageous. :-).  Please update us in 1 or 2 more weeks, and let us know what the boss says after he learns about your decision.

Answer (score 8):

It's your boss' job to take decision.

It's your job to provide information to your boss so that they can make informed decisions.

You can't do anything to change your boss' mind, just be sure that it is documented somewhere that you think Tom doesn't have what it takes and that you told your boss so. Because if Tom screw things up, it can happen that your boss will try to throw you under the bus.

Comment: Documentation is the key.  An unbiased third party should know that you were not on board with the boss' decision.

Comment: @sf02, It seems very difficult for the OP to document this case. The boss did not put anything in writing (email) when he asked the OP to proceed Tom to the next round. The boss is clever enough to only **VERBALLY** ask the OP to move TOM to the next round. So, the boss does not leave any paper trail to show that he violates the company policy in any way. How does the OP document the fact that the boss unfairly asks the OP to proceed TOM to the next round ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 The OP can't control what the boss sends by email but the OP can send an email of his own at every stage of this sham interview process outlining how the candidate is not a good fit and recommending to not have the candidate proceed.

Comment: I sent email detailing my feedback and recommendation to my boss and HR. I emphasized that I did my part on sharing my feedback. My boss will decide whether he wants to offer his friend the job

Answer (score 6):

> What should I do in this situation?

The decision isn't yours to make. Do what your boss told you to do.

Answer (score 6):

> What should I do in this situation?

If you cannot convince your boss that you are right, you get to decide if this is the hill you wish to die on.

- If yes, you can refuse to proceed Tom to the next step and hope you aren't fired for refusing to do what you are told.
- If no, you do what your boss tells you to do even when you don't agree with it.

Comment: This isn't a very thoughtful analysis. There is a strong suggestion here that the boss is not an owner, and that he is asking the OP for a favour, not issuing a formal direction on behalf of their employer. What the OP has in fact done - provide his own advice in writing, and allow the boss to make the hiring decision personally - is a much more reasonable response.

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is nepotism, depending on whether the boss is also the owner, this could be none of your business.

If the boss is not an owner, it could be viewed as nepotistic misuse of company funds - which possibly should be looked into. Whether you are that person, is another question.

If the boss is the owner, nepotistic decisions are theirs to make - and you should probably only raise the issue if the new hire is somehow a burden; as you would with any other non-performant co-worker.

I personally find it OK if an owner-boss hires unqualified family and friends - as long as their presence has no bearing on my work. They could be hired for old times sake or as a favor at a difficult time or other private reasons - which I find legitimate if the owner-boss is solely bearing the burden.

Comment: As you point out, nepotism isn't illegal (necessarily a bad thing) if it was, then you wouldn't have family working in family-owned businesses, and well, they wouldn't be "family owned and operated".  Lots of people take advantage of the fact, they know somebody, in order get an interview or a job